# Make vim put yanked items in the numbered registers

Tags: vim

I understand that the numbered registers 1-9 are only filled with things that were _d_eleted or _c_hanged, but is there a way to make _y_anked items also fill these buffers, short of defining a custom yank as a delete and put?

For instance, if I have

```
one
two
three
```

and I'm on line "one" and do `yykyykyy`, I'd expect register 3 to have "one", register 2 to have "two", and register 1 to have "three", with registers 4 and up having whatever was already there bumped up.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this script is what you're looking for? [YankRing](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1234) maintains a history of previous yanks, changes and deletes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
"3yyk"2yyk"1yyk
```